# Why can't I access my mongodb running in a docker container in Azure web apps?

Tags: mongodb, docker, azure-web-app-service

I want to run a mongodb docker image from dockerhub for example `mongo:3.6` or `mongo:4.1` in an Azure Web App but I can't access it from outside.

According to the Azure logs the docker container starts fine and the logs say:

`docker run -d -p 29794:27017 --name mytestapp -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=mytestapp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=27017 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=mytestappurl -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxx -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 mongo:4.1`

```
2019-06-15 19:42:49.831 INFO  - Container mytestapp for site mytestapp initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

As far as I understood so far [Azure Web App Service only supports port 80 and 443 for inbound traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic) and maps the internal port (in the case of the mongodb: 27017) to port 80 or 443, depending on SSL or not.

When I access my web app via browser and port 80 I get the message

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

which says the service is somehow accessible and is waiting for requests on port 80 but when I try to connect via mongo, for example:

```
mongo -host mytestappurl -port "80"  -username "root" -passwort "myrootpw" --verbose
```

I get

```
creating new connection to:mytestappurl:80
D NETWORK  [js] connected to server to:mytestappurl:80
I NETWORK  [js] recv(): message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000
```

and so on. I also tried to set the key/value pair WEBSITES_PORT=27017 in the Azure App settings but without success. The same setup runs fine locally and I can access the mongodb as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your database using Robomongo or any other similar app, use the Ip and port you have to create a new connection.